# ROW_NUMBER() in a view in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, view, ssms, row-number

I have tried the following query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
select 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ret_id, dep_id DESC) AS 'Row Number' 
from 
   Round_Trip_View
```

and it works.

I have tried the same to create a view, and it crashed.

Any idea?

I am looking to assign a kind of id for each row in my view and I appreciate any alternative ideas :)

Comment: It crashed! I guess the problem is the view wizard! I am trying the query of "Create view..."

Comment: Yes. it works! Should I remove my post?

Comment: maybe :D or you can answer your own question and mark it accepted. Thus sharing your knowledge with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the view wizard. 
What I learned: never use the wizards when you can code! :)