# The query in view can't be saved

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to change the existing view with new code:

```
with cte1 as (
SELECT    dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.ID, dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, dbo.T_Action.Artist, dbo.T_ActionTickets.ActionDate, dbo.T_ActionSeatsType.SeatType,
         dbo.T_ActionPlaceSeats.Seats, dbo.T_ActionTickets.RowNumber, dbo.T_ActionTickets.SeatNumber, dbo.T_ActionTickets.Price, dbo.T_TicketStatus.Name AS Status,
         dbo.T_Users.UserName, dbo.T_OrderTicket.OrderID, T_Users_1.UserName AS SalerName, dbo.T_Fiscal.DocNum, dbo.T_FiscalType.Name AS DocType,
         dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID, dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID, dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.UserID, dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.SalerID, dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.FiscalID,
         dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.BarCode, dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.ReservDate, dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.Created, dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.Comments,
         CASE WHEN StatusID IN (3, 10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID, T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID ORDER BY T_ActionTicketLog.Created) AS rn
FROM          dbo.T_Users AS T_Users_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_ActionPlaceSeats INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_ActionTicketLog INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_TicketStatus ON dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.StatusID = dbo.T_TicketStatus.ID INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_Action INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_ActionTickets ON dbo.T_Action.ID = dbo.T_ActionTickets.ActionID INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_ActionSeatsSubType ON dbo.T_ActionTickets.ActionSeatsSubTypeID = dbo.T_ActionSeatsSubType.ID ON 
         dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.ActionTicketID = dbo.T_ActionTickets.ID INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_ActionSeatsType ON dbo.T_ActionSeatsSubType.SeatsTypeID = dbo.T_ActionSeatsType.ID ON 
         dbo.T_ActionPlaceSeats.ID = dbo.T_ActionSeatsType.SeatsID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_Users ON dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.UserID = dbo.T_Users.ID ON T_Users_1.ID = dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.SalerID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_FiscalType INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_Fiscal ON dbo.T_FiscalType.ID = dbo.T_Fiscal.FiscalTypeID ON dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.FiscalID = dbo.T_Fiscal.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_OrderTicket ON dbo.T_ActionTicketLog.TicketOrderID = dbo.T_OrderTicket.ID
),
cte2 as (
   SELECT ActionTicketID, OrderTicketID, Created, TicketBarCode,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ActionTicketID ORDER BY Created) AS rn
   FROM T_TicketPrint
)
SELECT cte1.*, oa.TicketBarCode
FROM cte1
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT * FROM cte2
   WHERE cte1.ActionTicketID = cte2.ActionTicketID AND cte1.TicketOrderID = cte2.OrderTicketID AND cte1.rn = cte2.rn
) oa
order by dbo.func_ConvertToInt(cte1.SeatNumber), cte1.ActionTicketID, cte1.Created
```

When I try to save it, this error comes up: "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

What's wrong with the query?

Comment: I notice you have a `;` at the very beginning is that intentional?

Comment: Try getting rid of the initial semicolon.

Comment: It was intentional. But, when i remove it, the error is still there.

Comment: There's new error now. Please, take a look at updated original post.

Comment: I've made it work. The issue was in MS SQL Server Management Studio's wizard. When you write view manually, eveything works fine. Please, see this thread as reference:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280520/row-number-in-a-view-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` clause in the view doesn't make sense by itself. The rows in the view don't have any order in the same way, as rows in the table don't have any order.

So, you can either remove the `ORDER BY` clause from the view altogether, or leave `ORDER BY` and add `TOP (100) PERCENT` to the `SELECT` clause. Normally, it doesn't make sense to have `TOP (100) PERCENT` and `ORDER BY`, because it just slows down the query. `ORDER BY` in the view makes sense when `TOP` limits the number of rows somehow.

I want to make it clear. It is a common misunderstanding. If you define a view as:

```
CREATE VIEW SomeView
AS
SELECT TOP(100) PERCENT SomeColumn
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY SomeColumn
```

And then `SELECT` from that view without `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT SomeColumn
FROM SomeView
```

Then the order of rows returned as a result of this `SELECT` is not defined and can be any. Sometimes it may be ordered by `SomeColumn`, sometimes not. It depends on many things.
Only if you add `ORDER BY` to the final `SELECT` you'll get a guaranteed order:

```
SELECT SomeColumn
FROM SomeView
ORDER BY SomeColumn
```

Comment: I've already tried to use TOP(100) PERCENT, but still can't save it. What about ORDER BY clause in ROW_NUMBER function?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` does need `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause. I don't understand why with `TOP` you still can't save the view. Anyway, as I explained in the answer `TOP (100) PERCENT` is meaningless in the view, so you really should remove `order by dbo.func_ConvertToInt(cte1.SeatNumber), cte1.ActionTicketID, cte1.Created`. If you remove it from the view definition, can you save it?

Comment: I've made it work. The issue was in MS SQL Server Management Studio's wizard. When you write view manually, eveything works fine. Please, see this thread as reference:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280520/row-number-in-a-view-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't *normally* have `order by` in a view or subquery. If you really need an ordered output, try making use of the `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT` hack.

Put it in the final `select`

```
.
.
.
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT cte1.*, oa.TicketBarCode
FROM cte1
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT * FROM cte2
   WHERE cte1.ActionTicketID = cte2.ActionTicketID AND cte1.TicketOrderID = cte2.OrderTicketID AND cte1.rn = cte2.rn
) oa
order by dbo.func_ConvertToInt(cte1.SeatNumber), cte1.ActionTicketID, cte1.Created
```